# Regex to match repeated attribute values in a string

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex

I'm wondering if anyone knows if it's possible to write a regex to match repeated values in an `attr={value}` type string.

For example, in the string `<Grid xs={12} sm={12} md={12} lg={8} xl={12}>` I would replace the unnecessary breakpoints (unnecessary because they are already covered by the `xs` breakpoint) resulting in `<Grid xs={12} lg={8} xl={12}>`.

I have tried using a back-reference match which seems to work but seems this could be cleaner?

`(?:(?:xs|sm|md|lg|xl)=(\{\d{1,2}\}))(\s(?:xs|sm|md|lg|xl)=(\1))+`

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Please explain more about what you mean by "unnecessary breakpoints". Consider giving mutliple examples of things which should match and also things which should not match. Also, please demonstrate your own research efforts, by discussing regexes you have tried yourself and how they failed. All those details will help with making your question clearer.

Comment: May be: `str = str.replace/(={\d+})(?:\s+\w+\1)+/g, '$1')`

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, that's quite helpful!

Comment: @Yunnosch thanks for the feedback, I've edited the question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use this regex replacement in Javascript:

```
str = str.replace/(={\d+})(?:\s+\w+\1)+/g, '$1')
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/r4Pnyv/1)

**RegEx Details**

- `(={\d+})`: Match `=` followed by 1+ digits in capture group #1
- `(?:\s+\w+\1)+`: Match 1 or more instances of `key=value` pairs separated by 1+ whitespaces where `value` is back-reference of `\1` to ensure we match same number in `value.
- Replacement is `$1` to put captured value back in input

Comment: Thanks @anubhava, that formed a good basis for what I was looking for. In the end I used the following regex:
`(?:(xs|sm|md|lg|xl)=(\{\d{1,2}\}))(\s(?:xs|sm|md|lg|xl)=(\2))+` which checks for the specific attributes and then replaces them with the first found occurrence in VS code using `$1=$2`. I think your solution is cleaner.